# How to generate an Access Token with Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

In order to test my twitter-related methods I use an `Access Token` that I have generated on the Application Manager of the Twitter API. But that limits their use to my account.

I wish to have a user generate his own `Access Token` and `Access Token Secret` in order to apply my actions to his account.

How can that be done using the library `Twitter4j`?

Here's how I set my `OAuth` information so far:

```
 static Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

 public void authenticateUser() {
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET));
}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how access tokens are used. If you think about the fact that they are generated under 'Application Manager', it should be clear that you generate them on a per-application basis, not a per-user basis. I wouldn't be happy if I went to authenticate via Twitter and someone generated an access token using my account. Also, the ability to generate API access keys from the API itself seems like it would be open to misuse, so I wouldn't be surprised if you can't do it.

Comment: Oh, I thought Access Tokens were a per user thing (as opposed to consumer keys). How should my user authenticate himself then? And what should I retrieve in order to use this library's tools?

Comment: As I don't know what you want to accomplish I'm just guessing but I think you want #7 on [this page](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html). You redirect them to a web page which returns you an OAuth token, which allows you to do stuff that would usually require their username/pass.

Comment: An Oauth1 Access Token is per-user and per app.  You app is meant to keep it's consumer key and consumer secret hidden, and go through the authentication flow with the user.  At some point they are forwarded to the twitter.com website to login without your app intercepting and then they return to your app (either with a PIN or via a link with a code) after logging in and granting your app access to their account.

Comment: @Michael #7 has me get a PIN from my user (that I don't know how to get anyways), I wish to have my user simply authorize my application's access to his twitter and generate a token.